# Pandas data frame values are plotting with their individual labels and not on the correct scale

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas data frame,

```
 Time Sc Recovery Y Recovery  ... Tb Recovery Ho Recovery Bi Recovery
0   6:18:16        84.0       84.6  ...        90.1        91.3        88.2
1   6:20:13        92.5       82.5  ...        85.8        87.6        85.0
2   6:22:10        91.8       83.9  ...        85.2        85.1        84.2
3   6:24:07        94.1       82.5  ...        85.0        86.0        83.3
4   6:26:04        94.6       82.8  ...        86.5        86.7        85.2
5   6:28:01        95.1       83.1  ...        85.8        88.8        87.6
6   6:29:58        96.0       83.8  ...        86.8        85.6        84.7
```

And I am plotting all the Recovery columns against its associated time.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.tight_layout()
ax = adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='Sc Recovery', color='b', label='Sc 45')
adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='Y Recovery', color='r', label='Y 89', ax=ax)
adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='Rh Recovery', color='g', label='Rh 103', ax=ax)
adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='In Recovery', color='orange', label='IN 115', ax=ax)
adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='Tb Recovery', color='purple', label='Tb 159', ax=ax)
adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='Ho Recovery', color='cyan', label='Ho 165', ax=ax)
adf.plot(kind="scatter", x='Time', y='Sc Recovery', color='magenta',label='Bi 209', ax=ax)
```

However When I do this, the labels and the scales get all messed up.
[image: Entire plot, can see that the labels are unreadable]

Firstly it includes every single Recovery data point as a y tick, and every Time data point as an x tick.
I just want it to have a tick every few percent, so its less congested and looks better.

The other problem that I suspect is part of my first problem is that it doesn't put all the analytes on the same scale.
[image: Zoomed in to show that the data is simply placed on top of the previous column and is not even making a proper plot]

You can see that the numbers are not in ascending order, they just restart in the order in which I added the columns into the plot.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my values were not floats or integers, so matplotlib had no way of knowing where my values were to be placed.

If that doesn't fix your problem then try looking at this source I found for formating your x and y ticks:
https://www.overcoded.net/matplotlib-axis-ticks-frequency-331416/